# User Input as a Date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, input, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get the user to input a code and a date.  The user will first be prompted to enter the code and then the date.  This will display specific information to the user.

I am able to comment out the bottom two lines of code and successfully prompt the user for the code and receive the correct output.  When I uncomment out the bottom two lines of code, it successfully prompts the user for input(which the user would enter the date), but I get a compile error.

Here is my error I receive: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:     *Action:Error at Line: 22 Column: 44.

Here is my code:

```
       WHERE END_CODE.SP_CODE = '&Enter_Code'
       AND
       DATECHART.US_DATE = &Enter_Date;
```

Comment: What will the user be using to enter these parameters?

Comment: There is one database which will use the typical format for a date MM-DD-YY. Of course I will create separate programs for each. Another database will use DD-MMM-YY  with the Month in text form (jan, feb..ect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
   WHERE END_CODE.SP_CODE = '&Enter_Code'
   AND
   DATECHART.US_DATE = to_date('&Enter_Date','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Of course if user enters date in a format other than the one specified, it will fail.

For other input formats you can use to convert an input string into a date you can [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

Comment: What if the month in the database is listed in letter form such as 25-JAN-14.

Comment: @TitanC Oracle dates are not stored as strings, they are only converted to strings to print them. But if you want the user to enter the date in that format you can use 'dd-MON-yy'.

Comment: When I type in the revisions to my code I get this error now:  ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL
01797. 00000 -  "this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 22 Column: 40       This is referring to the comma

Answer (score 1):

Using `&` to get user input does not treat it as a bind variable - it performs a simple text substitution. So, consider, e.g., you're inputing a date like 1/2/2014:

```
WHERE END_CODE.SP_CODE = 'someCode'
AND
DATECHART.US_DATE = 1/2/2014;
```

The slashes are interpreted as division operators (i.e. one divided by two divided by two thousand and fourteen, which is 0.00024826216). Since 0.00024826216 is not a date, you get an error.

One way around this is to input the date as a string, and explicitly handle its conversion:

```
WHERE END_CODE.SP_CODE = '&Enter_Code'
AND
DATECHART.US_DATE = TO_DATE('&Enter_Date', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```